# getting the following error in installing qt creator through software center

Tags: apt, software-center, qt

getting the following error in installing qt creator through software center.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

qtcreator: Depends: libqt4-help (>= 4:4.7.1) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4 is to be installed
           Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15) but 2.15-0ubuntu10.2 is to be installed
           Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.6.3-1ubuntu5 is to be installed
           Depends: libqt4-declarative (>= 4:4.7.4) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2 is to be installed
           Depends: libqt4-designer (>= 4:4.7.1) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4 is to be installed
           Depends: libqt4-network (>= 4:4.7.1) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2 is to be installed
           Depends: libqt4-script (>= 4:4.7.1) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2 is to be installed
           Depends: libqt4-sql (>= 4:4.7.1) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2 is to be installed
           Depends: libqt4-svg (>= 4:4.7.1) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2 is to be installed
           Depends: libqt4-xml (>= 4:4.7.1) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2 is to be installed
           Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2 is to be installed
           Depends: libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2 is to be installed
           Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.4.0) but 4.6.3-1ubuntu5 is to be installed
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: the version is ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the QT-SDK from http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/qt-sdk.
I just did on Ubuntu 12.04.